# Retry REST API request

Tags: javascript, node.js

In our project we are invoking an REST API exposed by payment service provider to submit payment information. We are making a Node JS based HTTP Post request to invoke the API. Since its a POST request I wanted to know if its a good practice to retry the request for specific number of times in case the API was down or if we  are not getting any response from the API. What is the best practice (in Node JS), should we invoke the API just once or we should retry for specific number of times?

And just FYI The Payment provider has confirmed that  we can make the same request more than once and they  will treat it as idempotent request

Comment: If the payment provider says it's fine? Why do you need confirmation from random strangers on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

in general , it's common to send the payment info in a single post request and parse the response from the payment API provider and prompting the customer with the corresponding message , don't resend the post request with such sensetive creditcard credentials with no specific urgent reason .

ie:
- (server side message) payment service is not reachable => (client side message) the payment service is currently unavailable , please try again later

- (server side message) payment information is wrong => (client side message) payment information you entered are not valid

... etc

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sometimes it happen when there API goes down, if they say you can retry for specified number of time then you can. There is not a problem with but be sure not to do payment twice.
You can also get the payments of each user from payment gateways API's to ensure is the payment to a purchase has been done or not before retrying to charge.